# How to read data from oracle stored procedure value into dropdownlist in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I am new in programming. I want to read data from oracle proceedure and this value is assigned to the dropdownlist in asp.net..

This is my procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Frm_Dealer_list(
C_DEALER_DTL_OUT OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

IS

BEGIN

  OPEN C_DEALER_DTL_OUT FOR

    SELECT FLD001 DlrID, FLD002 DlrCODE, FLD003 DlrNAME
     FROM PT001 ORDER BY FLD003;
END FRM_DEALER_LIST_PRC_2_4;
```

I want to read dlrCODE and this will be displayed into the drop down in asp.net page
Ang I have write the code like this

```
 con.Open();
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Frm_Dealer_list_Prc_2_4");
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("DlrID", OracleType.Cursor);
    cmd.Parameters["DlrID"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    OracleParameter op = new OracleParameter();
    OracleParameter oraP = new OracleParameter();

    OracleDataReader reader = new OracleDataReader();
    oraP.OracleType=OracleType.Cursor;
    oraP.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(oraP);




    if(reader.Read())
    {
        ddl_DealerCode.DataSource=reader;
        ddl_DealerCode.DataTextField="DlrID";
        ddl_DealerCode.DataBind();

    }
```

pls help me to solve it I am new in asp.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use data set in asp my friend:

```
con.Open();
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("Frm_Dealer_list_Prc_2_4", con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("DlrID", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
da.Fill(ds);
comboBox1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
comboBox1.ValueMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns["DlrCODE"];
comboBox1.DisplayMember = ds.Tables[0].Columns["DlrNAME"];
comboBox1.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
```